# Qt How to draw a parallel double line bezier curve in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to draw a parallel double line Bezier curve in QML as below, how may I do so?

[parallel double line curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfzez.png)

Comment: For what? is that an animation? a chart?

Comment: It is for an image only, not animation.

Comment: The BezierCurveTo method will draw only a single line Bezier curve, not double line curve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just draw two curves with [this API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#bezierCurveTo-method) with a slight shift. There is not anything specific about "double curves" other than drawing two curves with a shift.

```
ctx.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 0);//start point
ctx.bezierCurveTo(-10, 90, 210, 90, 180, 0);
ctx.stroke();
```

You will need to sort out the specifics, `(cp1x, cp1y)` and `(cp2x, cp2y)`, to have the shape you want, but this seems to be the way to draw Bézier curves.

[image]

Comment: The problem is when the curve gets complicated, e.g.  When the 4 points of the curve is (200,200), (0,0), (0,0), (500,200). The 2 curves will cross each other. But what I needed is parallel lines curve

Comment: ? Curve math is curve math that you figure out. That is not the responsibility of QML. This is not any different with QML, QtWidgets, Flutter, Electron or any other framework. What you want is a very specific Bézier curve drawing, which is fine, you go and figure out the math for that. This is the QML interface in the answer to draw Bézier curves. Actually, even the math is fairly simple for parallel curves. But again, this was a QML question, not math question. You need focus in your question. QML and math are two different things.

Comment: Can you show the math for parallel curves? Thanks! Also, if QML supports something like a hollow line, then this problem will be solved. So it can also be considered a QML question.

Comment: No, this was a question tagged with qml. You will need to ask a new math question tagged for math, and math experts will help you. I think your question will likely be closed without focus. When you ask QML questions, you get QML answers, not math answers. It is also a bit concerning that you have not tried anything yourself, just ask for a full qml and math solution.

Comment: The question has been retagged with Math

Comment: You asked a qml question. It will have to stay like that since you already got a question for that. So, you should not invalidate answers. I already said that you will have to ask a new question for the math. Unless someone is happy to help you here to give a full solution without you trying anything yourself.

Comment: Also, a quick googling shows this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18017438/2682142 - and the math further explained here in details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve - it is not fit for Stack Overflow to try nothing, but get everything. We are here to teach you how to fish, not to fish for you =)